# Dealing with a Future wrapped with Try in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, error-handling, future

I have a repo method that returns a future:

```
def insert(newUser: User): Future[User]
```

This method can fail for different reasons, however, I want to be able to catch one of these reasons and rethrow others.
If I am simply wrapping the call with Try

```
Try(userRepository.insert(usr)) match {
      case Success(newUserFuture) => newUserFuture

      case Failure(e) if e.getCause.getMessage.contains("duplicate key") => {
        logger.warn(e.getMessage)
        throw DuplicateEntityException("duplicate user record")
      }

      case Failure(e) => {
        logger.error(e.getMessage)
        throw e
      }
    }
```

As a result, I am getting `Try[Future[User]]`, and in this situations, neither of the Failures will ever happen, since the Future is successfully created.
And at this point, I am not sure how to deal with it. Ideally, I want to get `Future[Either[String, User]]` out of it (or something similar).

How should I deal with this situation, or am I in completely wrong direction?

**EDIT following recommendations**
**Possible solution**
I've tried something like this:

```
userRepository.insert(usr).map(newUser => Right(newUser)) recoverWith {
      case e: PSQLException if e.getMessage.contains("duplicate key") =>
        Future.successful(Left("duplicate user record"))
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Future` will handles the exceptions for you. You need not wrap future code with `Try`.

`Future` does the job of the `Try` as well.

This line of code is not necessary

```
Try(userRepository.insert(usr))
```

I hope your insert method is something like this

```
def insert(newUser: User): Future[User] = Future { doSomeDBCall() }
```

In the above method. If `doSomeDBCall()` fails. The exception will be caught by the future safely and will be delivered to caller as `Failure(exception)`. So you need not wrap the `Future` with a `Try`

Catch specific exceptions and throw others (propagate others).

You can use `recoverWith` and handle exceptions and propagate exceptions which you are not interested in.

In the below code `SQLException` is handled and other exceptions are propagated to the caller.

```
userRepository.insert(usr).recoverWith { 
 case ex: SQLException => Future.successful(defaultValue)
 case ex => Future.failed(ex)
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I get what you mean

Comment: @ShurikAgulyansky added explanation

Comment: So how do I unwrap the future so I can catch only one type of exception and not others?

Comment: @ShurikAgulyansky added explanation

Answer (score 1):

I think you can reverse your approach, and use a guard in the case clean the code up a little.  First up is to have `userRepository.insert(usr)` return a `Future[Try[User]]`, which allows you to just map the future, e.g.

```
def insert(user: User): Future[Try[User]]
```

which can then be used like this:

```
userRepository.insert(user).map {
    case Success(insertedUser) => Right(insertedUser)
    case Failure(ex) if ex.getCause.getMessage.contains("duplicate key") => throw DuplicateEntityException("duplicate user record")
    case Failure(ex) => throw ex
}
```

The result of this will be a `Future[User]` that you can attach callbacks to (see http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) to either do something else with the user or deal with the exception.

Comment: Unfortunately, `insert` method is outside of my control. Otherwise I would do  exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

```
def futureToFutureTry[T](f: Future[T]): Future[Try[T]] =
   f.map(Success(_)).recover {
     case e: Throwable => {
      Failure(e)
   }
}

...
userRepository.insert(usr) map futureToFutureTry
```

for checking

```
def checkOperations[A](operations: List[Try[A]]): Future[List[A]] = {
   Future {
      if (!operations.filter(_.isFailure).isEmpty) {
       // there were some error

      } else {
       // all operations are ok
     }
}
```

Comment: The solution I provided in the post worked exactly as I expected.